# Spark Kafka Streaming - Send original timestamp rather than current timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using spark Structured streaming to send records to a kafka topic. The kafka topic is created with the config - `message.timestamp.type=CreateTime`

This is done so that the target Kafka topic records have the same timestamp as the original Records.

My kafka streaming code :

```
kafkaRecords.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS BINARY)","CAST(timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)")
    .write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","IP Of kafka")
    .option("topic",targetTopic)
    .option("kafka.max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", "1")
    .option("checkpointLocation",checkPointLocation)
    .save()
```

However, this does not preserve the original timestamp that is 2018/11/04, instead the timestamp reflects the latest date 2018/11/9.

On another note, just to confirm that kafka config is functioning, when I explicitly create a Kafka Producer and producer records having the timestamp and send that across, the original timestamp is preserved.

How can I get the same behaviour in Kafka Structured Streaming as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateTime` config of a topic would mean when the records are created, that is the time you get.

It's not clear where you're reading the data and seeing the timestamps, if you are running the producer code "today", that's the time they get, not before.

If you want timestamps of the past, you'll need to actually make your `ProducerRecord`s contain that timestamp by using the constructor that includes a timestamp parameter, but Spark does not expose it.

If you put just the timestamp in the payload value, as you're doing, that's the time you'll want to be doing analysis on, probably, not a `ConsumerRecord.timestamp()`

---

If you want to exactly copy data from one topic to another, Kafka uses MirrorMaker to accomplish this. Then you only need config files, not writing&deploying Spark code

Comment: Hi, I am reading the data from a parquet file, which in turn contains kafka records, cold-stored. Thus it already has the timestamps. When needed, these records are filtered, between two timestamp values and pushed to another kafka topic. The only pain-point with creating Kafka Producer records is that it impacts the performance drastically for example, i was able to replay 2.5 million records in 2 minutes using Spark Streaming, but if I do the same replay using my own Kafka Producer (with producer records having the timestamp), it takes almost 1.5 hours. ...

Comment: You can convert the read Parquet into an RDD, then do `forEachPartition`, then within that, you could manually create a Producer object, then looping over all records of the partition to send them to Kafka